# How to prevent automatic escaping of special characters in Python

Tags: python, escaping, special-characters

I'm writing a Python script that accepts file paths as strings, parses them, appends a command name, and builds a list, which is then passed to `subprocess.Popen()` for execution.  This script is to handle both Unix and Windows file paths, and ultimately should run on both systems.

When I run this under Unix, if I give a Windows path that inadvertently contains an escape character (e.g. `\Users\Administrator\bin`), Python will interpret the embedded `\b` as the backspace character.  I want to prevent that from happening.

As far as I know, there's no function or method to denote a string variable as a raw string.  The `'r'` modifier only works for string constants.

So far, the closest I've been able to get is this:

```
winpath = "C:\Users\Administrator\bin" 
winpath = winpath.replace('\b','\\b')
winpathlist = winpath.split('\\')
```

At this point, winpathlist should contain `['C:','Users','Administrator','bin']`, not `['C','Users','Administrator\x08in']`.

I can add additional calls to `winpath.replace()` to handle the other escapes I might get -- `\a`, `\f`, `\n`, `\r`, `\t`, `\v` -- but not `\x`.

Is there a more pythonic way to do this?

Comment: How are you getting the value into the string? Python shouldn't treat the \b as an escape unless it's in a string literal, or gets into the string as an escape to begin with. (Also, forward slashes work just fine.)

Comment: @Wooble: Right now, it's coming in via doctest.

    >>> myCommandObject.setExcecutablePath('C:\Program Files\cygwin\cdrive\bin')

where myCommandObject contains a command name (e.g. 'ps'), a path, and a list of arguments.  

Changing the slashes from backslashes to forward slashes is not an option; my customer explicitly stated that this is what he wanted.

Comment: As I said, r only works for string literals; it does not work for string variables.  I look at the leading r as a kluge.

Anyway, here's the doctest (or part of it):
        >>> myCommand.setExecutablePath('C:\Program Files\cygwin\cdrive\bin')
        >>> myCommandList = myCommand.getLaunchList()
        >>> myCommandList
        ['C:\\\\Program Files\\\\cygwin\\\\cdrive\\\\bin\\\\ps', '-e', '-f']
        >>> myCommandList[0].split("\\\\")
        ['C:', 'Program Files', 'cygwin', 'cdrive', 'bin', 'ps']

I'm no longer getting any errors, now that I added the call to replace.

Comment: Forgot to thank Wooble for the help and suggestions.  After consulting with my customer, he opted to move the Windows path test out of the doctest and into a separate file.

Answer (score 20):

If your `winpath` is hard-coded, you may want to use `r` before your string to indicate it is a ["raw string"](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html).

```
winpath = r"C:\Users\Administrator\bin"
```

If `winpath` cannot be hardcoded, you can try to create a new string as:

```
escaped_winpath = "%r" % winpath
```

(which is just `repr(winpath)`, and won't really help you, as `repr("\bin")` is...)

A solution would be to rebuild the string from scratch: you can find an example of function at [that link](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/65211-convert-a-string-into-a-raw-string/), but the generic idea is:

```
escape_dict={'\a':r'\a',
             '\b':r'\b',
             '\c':r'\c',
             '\f':r'\f',
             '\n':r'\n',
             '\r':r'\r',
             '\t':r'\t',
             '\v':r'\v',
             '\'':r'\'',
             '\"':r'\"'}

def raw(text):
    """Returns a raw string representation of text"""
    new_string=''
    for char in text:
        try: 
            new_string += escape_dict[char]
        except KeyError: 
            new_string += char
    return new_string
```

and now, `raw("\bin")` gives you `"\\bin"` (and not `"\\x08in"`)...

Comment: I'm not familiar with repr().  Is it in 2.6?  I like this idea, and will hang on to this in case I need it in the future.  At the request of my customer, I pulled out the calls to replace().  Instead, he suggested that I move the Windows path test out of the doctest and into a separate file.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 7):

You can create a raw string by prepending r to the string literal notation

```
r"hello\nworld"
```

becomes

```
"hello\\nworld"
```

You can read some more [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals)

Comment: Negative.  If I put in the r in the doctest string as you suggest, it becomes part of the string.

Comment: @poltr1 Wrong. "r" does not become "r" anywhere, it just makes the format.